# How to get a reference to the hash being operated on within methods like reject?

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner approach to this:

```
hash = { 1 => 10, 2 => 33, 3 => 5, 4 => 33 }
hash.reject { |key, value| value != hash.values.max }.keys
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
{ 1 => 10, 2 => 33, 3 => 5, 4 => 33 }.reject { |key, value| value != HASH_BEING_OPERATED_ON.values.max }.keys
```

But the block within reject needs a reference to the hash that reject is operating upon. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides whether possible or not, you shouldn't be doing that because it is inefficient. You are recalculating the max value within each iteration. Why not just calculate max before iteration?

```
max = hash.values.max
hash.select{|_, value| value == max}.keys
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I should have realized it would certainly be the case with a dynamic language. Is your use of `_` convention for the case where a value is not used?

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little weird, but it is a one-liner that works without being inefficient:

```
hash.group_by{|_,v|v}.sort.last.last.transpose.first

#=> [2,4]
```

Comment: Even though it is not at ineffective as the original, I think `sort` is much heavier than `max`, and also `transpose` should be heavy. What about using `max_by`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it would be more efficient if `.sort.last` was replaced by `.max_by{|a| a[-1][-1]}`. I don't think the transpose would be too heavy, as it is small at that point.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't generally possible because it isn't generally good practice. Modifying a collection in the middle of a loop can lead to unexpected results.

Say `Array#each_with_index` set the `self` variable within the block to the array over which you were iterating. Rather than resulting in the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 8]`, this loop now becomes infinite:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each_with_index do |number, index|
  self << number * 2 if number % 2 == 0
end
```

Of course, there's nothing stopping you from doing this anyway with local variables, but by explicitly allowing access to the array within the loop, Ruby would be making these sorts of mistakes a lot more common.

I'm not suggesting that that's what you're doing in your example. I'm just stating what I imagine was a language design consideration.

Comment: I agree -- there are a lot of potential issues if it was allowed.